# Selecting unique data

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I  can't seem to find a good way to select unique data. Specifically unique values within a query.

Here's an example:
A `select distinct` query returns 10,000 rows. Within those rows, one column - let's call it vendors - has maybe 6 unique values. How can I return just the 6 unique vendors without scrolling through 10,000 records to make sure I caught them all. Even sorting by vendor this would still be a daunting task.

Comment: Use either `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` keywords in your query: `SELECT DISTINCT VENDOR FROM TABLE` _**or**_ `SELECT VENDOR FROM TABLE GROUP BY VENDOR`; both return the same results.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct vendor from (select [distinct] col1, col2, ..., vendor from your_table) temp;
```

On the other hand you could ask directly for the `distinct vendor`, without running the more expensive query:

```
select distinct vendor from yourtable where {your_criteria}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shoud try to give alias to your query result that returns 10k rows

something like (SELECT DISTINCT FROM ... ) as  yourtable

and then do SELECT DISTINCT your column name FROM yourtable

(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM xxx ) as yourtable // this would return your 10k rows and nam that table simply yourtable

and then SELECT DISTINCT youruniquecolumn FROM yourtable // this will select all unique columns from your 10k table